# how to spoof mac address using java code?

Tags: java, windows, networking, mac-address

i am writing a network utility program(for windows) in java..
i want to change/spoof the mac address of my network adapter.. how do i do that?
it would be great if there is any method to do this work..

my approach is going like this by executing three commands..

//Disable network adapter
netsh interface set interface name="Local Area Connection" admin=DISABLED

//this is what im not getting.. lets say i want my new spoofed address to be 00112233445566, how to do that...? didnt find any cmd command for changing mac address.. need your help here in finding if there is any cmd statement or any java method that does the job

//Enable network adapter
netsh interface set interface name="Local Area Connection" admin=ENABLED

thanks, will be waiting for your help :)

Comment: Easiest approach would be to buy a cheap router that has the capability to do MAC spoofing and use that. Instead of plugging your computer into the LAN, plug it into the router and then the router into the LAN. Then fire up a browser on the computer and access the Admin settings of the router and set it up.

Answer (score 3):

After messing with this a bit, I found an easy way to do this. Windows stores the spoofed MAC at this location in the registry:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}\0007

by the name "NetworkAddress"="00E04D18XXXX"

I messed with `cmd` to see if there was any way to edit the registry using cmd; the below command does the job perfectly

```
reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}\0007 /t REG_SZ /v NetworkAddress /d XXXXXXXXXXXX /f
```

Then this would be your Java code:

```
mac = textField.getText();

String commandChangeMac = "reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\Class\\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}\\0007 /t REG_SZ /v NetworkAddress /d " + mac + " /f";

obj.executeCommand(commandChangeMac);
```

Answer (score 0):

Write your own subclass of SocketImpl which will need to use JNI code for raw sockets.  Note that raw sockets will require privileged operations on most OS's.

Answer (score 0):

String mac = "2d345678U987";

```
Process p = Runtime
                .getRuntime() .exec("cmd /c start cmd.exe /K \"  \"reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\Class\\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}\\0007 /t REG_SZ /v NetworkAddress /d " + mac + " /f ");
```